# Cannot connet to sftp server from windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, sftp, ssh.net

I'm  working on windows service that uploads files to sftp server using SSH.NET. Problem is when I run code responsible for sending file from windows console app everything works fine, but when exact the same code is running from windows service i recive exception when connecting to SFTP : "A connection can not be made because the target computer actively refuses it"

I have SFTP server running on the same machine for testing.

```
    public void Send(string host, string userName, int port, string password, string filePath)
    {
        var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(host, userName, new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(userName, password));
        try
        {
            var sftpClient = new SftpClient(connectionInfo);            
            sftpClient.Connect(); // exception occurs there
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
            {
                sftpClient.UploadFile(fileStream, $"{Path.GetFileName(filePath)}", true);
            }
            sftpClient.Disconnect();
            sftpClient.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Logger.Log($"{host} | {password} | {port} | {userName}");
            Logger.Log(exception.Message);
            Logger.Log(exception.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going on? I think that can be some configuration problem because like I said the same code runs fine from console app.

Comment: Check permissions on the user that runs the Windows Service and the permissions on the service itself

Comment: did you manage to solve this? if yes, please tell me what permission was missing

Comment: @anky_91 that was no permission problem, that was code problem

Comment: @piotreqd yes, thanks, just fixed it today :)